# Running operations with Python Classes

Tags: python

For my IS computer science class, we are learning how to use classes. This is a section that I have had the hardest time understanding and I have been trying to work out all of the problems that I can possibly find, but I keep getting stuck. One of them goes as follows:

1. Define a class `GymStats`, that stores a person's name and squat and deadlift (in pounds) for a series of workouts.
2. The constructor should accept a single argument, the person's name.
3. The method `addStats(s, d)` should add the data (2 numbers in units of pounds) from a single workout.
4. There should be two other methods `getSquatStats()` and `getDeadliftStats()`, each of which return a length 3 tuple of min, max, and average for the respective exercise.
5. The last method, `showAll()`, prints the person's entire list of entered stats.

Here is the example given:

```
 >>>g = GymStats('Andrew')
 >>>g.addStats(200,250)
 >>>g.addStats(220, 300)
 >>>g.addStats(234, 284)
 >>>g.GetSquatsStats()
 (200, 234, 218)
 >>>g.getDeadliftStats()
 (250, 234, 218)
 >>>g.showAll()
 Andrew's gym stats:
 Squat:   Deadlift
 200      250
 220      300
 234      284
```

This is all I have so far:

```
class GymStats:
    def __init__(self, s, d):
        self.s = s

    def addStats(s,d):
        'nothing yet'

    def getSquatStats():
        count = 0
        for int in s:
            count += 
        return (min(s), max(s), 

    def getDeadLiftStats():
        count 2 - =

        return (min(d), max(d), 

    def showAll()
        print s 'gym stat"s':
            return ('Squat'.... 'Deadlift')
```

I don't know how to average the numbers between the lines so I have been stuck on that. And I am not sure which commands should go where. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started:

```
class GymStats:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.squats = []
        self.deadlifts = [] # now every object (instantiation) of class GymStats has a name, a squats that is an list and a deadlifts that is a list

    def addStats(self, squat, deadlift):
        self.squats.append(squat)
        self.deadlifts.append(deadlift) # since GymStats can only be made via __init__, we know for a fact that squats and deadlifts exist and are lists

    def GetSquatsStats(self):
        return (min(self.squats), max(self.squats)) # now add the average as the third tuple member
```

To find the average of a list of numbers, you need to find two things:

-the sum of all the numbers (hint: there is a built in function in python that does this)

-how many numbers are in the list (again, a built-in for this)

Then you just divide one by the other.

The rest should be obvious from here.

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks, I am too used to Java/C# where you can leave out this whenever it's not ambiguous.